# How to hide controls without record in Json string

Tags: arrays, json, vba

I need some help on how to make sure that some controls in Json string should not appear on the string if the Ms Access record source is showing blank/Empty record see below:

```
[
   {
      "ItemNumber": 1,
      "SalesDate": "2019-09-14",
      "ProductName": "Pepsi (Rgb 350 ML)",
      "BarCode": "6009803227328",
      "Qty": 165,
      "Price": 53.5,
      "VAT": Null
      "TotalPrice": 10239.9
   },
```

Let us assume VAT control in MS Access record source is empty/blank, then the string should look like below:

```
[
   {
      "ItemNumber": 1,
      "SalesDate": "2019-09-14",
      "ProductName": "Pepsi (Rgb 350 ML)",
      "BarCode": "6009803227328",
      "Qty": 165,
      "Price": 53.5,
      "TotalPrice": 10239.9
   },
```

Kindly see if it is possible to sort out this.

Below is the sample actual VBA code that supply the Json string. Assuming Tax Class B is EMPTY/BLANK instead of showing null in the ARRAY I do not want it to show anything here:

```
 Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassA", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
    Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
```

Comment: It’s difficult to answer your question without knowing how you are creating the JSON. Clarify, please?

Comment: The record source for Json is an Ms access Parameter query, The Json module is does the conversion as parameters in VBA. Please the edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to add the value to Tax if it is not null or blank, then check for those conditions before calling Tax.Add.

```
Dim myvar As Variant

    myvar = DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
    If Not IsNull(myvar) Then
        If Len(myvar) > 0 Then
            Tax.Add myvar
        End If
    End If
```

Note: Getting a set of values from a record one by one is the slow way. You may want to look at DAO (or ADO depending on the application) which allows you to get an entire record at once.