# How to filter blank arrays using Access VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I have an array Tax class B in Ms Access.

Tax class B has some empty values. These arrays are generated from the code below:

```
Tax.Add DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
Like say: if i = 5 then
 "B"
  ""
 "B"
 ""
 "B"
```

How can I get rid of those empty elements so that Tax class B becomes only three elements long and then display them in a range of three cells?

I tried the code below

```
Dim myvar As Variant

myvar = DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i))
If Not IsNull(myvar) Then
    If Len(myvar) > 0 Then
        Tax.Add myvar
    End If
End If
```

Comment: That code didn't solve your issue because it is the solution to a different problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455560/how-to-hide-controls-without-record-in-json-string/59474665#59474665

Where are you getting this array from a single DLookup? Is TaxClassB a multivalue field? And what do you mean by displaying the results in cells?

Comment: Sorry its NOT a cell but a field , this field is optional it may be required or may not that is why if its empty it should not show on the on Json string which is being supplied by by the dlook up , please note the rest of the code which supplies this Json string is okay its this part which is optional that the one to be sorted out

Comment: I'd say the DLookup is missing also testing for the value of the column in question. It's testing the InvoiceID, the ItemesID, but what is the field that's being returned? Only return that field when it's not "empty" and there should be no need for post-processing...

Comment: The field returned is "TaxClassB"

Comment: Add check for Is Null to query crriteria as @cindy suggested`"InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i) & " And TaxClassB Not Is Null"` If you use a recordset on that query  you could fetch all elements in one query and if you need an array (what for?) m you can use`.GetRows`to convert the recordset to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could filter out the null or empty string values as part of your DLookup criteria?

Changing your line:

```
"InvoiceID=" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID=" & CStr(i)
```

to something along the lines of:

```
"InvoiceID=" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID=" & CStr(i) & Nz(TaxClassB, "") <> ""
```

Should do the trick, returning you with a fully populated array.